# Jquery number of clicks record

Tags: jquery

I am working on this page where I'm using a Jquery Mp3 Player (Jplayer) with its playlist. What I want to do is very simple in theory: I want to record the number of clicks for every playlist element.

- When someone enters the page, his number of clicks are at 0 for every element.
- The visitor can click a few times on element #1, then go to element #2 (which will be at 0), then come back to element #1 and the number of clicks must be saved.
- We don't need to save it for next visits.

Jplayer has this function that loads each time a new playlist element is being loaded: `function playListChange( index )`

In which every element has its own ID dynamically updated: `myPlayList[index].song_id`

Here's my code:

```
function playListChange( index ) {
var id = myPlayList[index].song_id;
if(!o) { var o = {}; }
if(!o[id]) { o[id] = 0; }
alert(o[id]);
… $("#mydiv").click { o[id] = o[id]+1; } …
```

But o[id] is reset every time and the alert always shows 0. Why?

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the scope of the variable `o`. If you define it using the `var` function, it will only exist for one invocation of the function. Try

```
function playListChange( index ) {
var id = myPlayList[index].song_id;
if(!window.o) { window.o = {}; }
if(!window.o[id]) { window.o[id] = 0; }
alert(window.o[id]);
… $("#mydiv").click { window.o[id] = window.o[id]+1; } …
```

That should force it into the global scope (a property of `window`, the global call object in client-side JavaScript) and it should work.

Edit: this explicit way of making the variable a `window` property is the safest, I guess.

There is [an excellent explanatory article on scope in JavaScript here](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer I wasn't aware of this. But now the alert doesn't show up anymore?

Comment: Oops, I might have been too naive in guessing JavaScript's abilities/peculiarities. See my revised version.

Comment: AHHH very nice, it's working!! :) Thank you for your fast help.

Comment: Hmm, as a matter of fact I still have one problem. If I'm on element #1 and I go on element #2 and then click on #mydiv, the counter is increases first for element #1, then the ID is updated and then only the counter is increased for number #2. Is there a way to lower the priority of $("mydiv").click?

Comment: I have no idea what 'element #1', 'element #2' and '#mydiv' are, or what's going on in general. I suggest you either extend your question or post a new one, detailing what's happening to which elements in what order. I don't think jQuery can prioritize handlers :(

Answer (score 1):

The first answer here is correct in part, but I don't think his suggestion works.  The issue is definitely variable scoping, but just removing the var command won't push the variable to the global scope if it doesn't exist.  You need to place `var o = {};` outside of your playListChange function.  Something like this:

```
var o = {};

function playListChange( index ) {
  var id = myPlayList[index].song_id;
  if(!o[id]) { o[id] = 0; }
  alert(o[id]);
  $("#mydiv").click { ++o[id]; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, good one! I'll add the `window` possibility as an option.